# Use a Field Value in MongoDB lookup pipeline

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, pipeline

I'm using a materialized path structure to describe a tree in MongoDB - I'm using a plugin for this which works with most of my queries. However, I have a particular use case where it would be useful for me to create an aggregate to get all groups which match a criteria along with their children. The documents look a bit like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  name: 'Parent',
  path: '',
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  name: 'Child',
  path: '<id of parent>[#]',
}
```

I need to be able to include the parent path in a regular expression in order to run a lookup on the same table and join all of the child documents. The following query doesn't work, but I was wondering if this sort of thing is possible, or even if it's a smart idea?

```
await Groups
  .aggregate()
  .match(getParams(params, context))
  .lookup({
    from: 'groups',
    as: 'children',
    pipeline: [{ $match: { path: { $regex: '^$path[#]' } } }],
  });
```

You can see that I'm trying to use the `$path` value in the regex in the pipeline. If this isn't possible, or simply not a great idea, is there another way of getting all the documents and their children using an aggregate in a different way?

Comment: So you're trying to use `lookup` to get data from the same collection you're aggregating from?

Comment: I'm trying to get parent groups with their children avoiding n+1 if possible. I guess doing a lookup on the same table is the same as getting the parent groups, looping through them and getting all the children so perhaps this isn't the solution.